# Writing to file from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to write a method in java to write data from an array to a text file but I'm getting two errors.

```
public void WriteStudentDetailsToFile() {
  PrintWriter out = null;
  try {
    out = new PrintWriter("StudentDetails.txt");
  } catch (FileNotFoundException ex)  {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("in " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    System.exit(1);
  } 


  for (int i = 0; i < enrolment.length; i += 1) {
    if (enrolment[i] != null) {
        Student a = this.enrolment[i];
        if (a.getName().equals("") || a.getAddress().equals("") || a.getDOB().equals("") || a.getGender().equals("")) {
            break;
        } else {
            String record = a.getName() + "\t" + "0" + "\t" + a.getAddress() + "\t" a.getDOB() + "\t" + a.getGender();
            out.println(record);
        }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

The two errors are

C:\Users\B00661059\Downloads\Assignment 2\Assignment 2\Student_Enrolment.java:137: error: ';' expected
                String record = a.getName() + "\t" + "0" + "\t" + a.getAddress() + "\t" a.getDOB() + "\t" + a.getGender();

^
C:\Users\B00661059\Downloads\Assignment 2\Assignment 2\Student_Enrolment.java:137: error: not a statement
                String record = a.getName() + "\t" + "0" + "\t" + a.getAddress() + "\t" a.getDOB() + "\t" + a.getGender();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 137, you need to add a concatenation operator (`+`) here:

```
"\t" + a.getDOB()
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious error is that you are missing a plus here: `+ "\t" a.getDOB() +`.

It should be

```
String record = a.getName() + "\t" + "0" + "\t" + a.getAddress() + "\t" + a.getDOB() + "\t" + a.getGender();
```

You might also want to look into how to define and use a `toString()` function in your Student class to control the string representation of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String record = a.getName() + "\t" + "0" + "\t" + a.getAddress() + "\t" + a.getDOB() + "\t" + a.getGender();
```

instead of this :

```
String record = a.getName() + "\t" + "0" + "\t" + a.getAddress() + "\t" a.getDOB() + "\t" + a.getGender();
```

Also this doesn't make sense :

```
if (a.getName().equals("") || a.getAddress().equals("") || a.getDOB().equals("") || a.getGender().equals("")) {
        break;
    }
```

Since you are only interested in the else branch you can negate it.

```
if !(a.getName().equals("") || a.getAddress().equals("") || a.getDOB().equals("") || a.getGender().equals("")) {
        // Do what you want
    }
```